# React Components overlapping each other (MaterialUI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am starting a project using React and MaterialUI. Almost finished with the initial setup but I found an issue and Im not aware of its reason here.

I have a simple navbar but another content that I use is under this navbar (navbar overlaps it).

I created code sandbox where this issue happens: https://codesandbox.io/s/n0zz7l35jm

Could anyone explain to me the reason of this behaviour and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. `<AppBar />` needs `position` property.

This fixes the problem

Thanks to anyone who tried to find out.